# Activerecord callback to modify associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 models with an association.  I want to setup a before_save in one model to modify the other.  Here is what I have:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leads
end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save  :update_event
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:title].blank? }

  def update_event
    self.events.title = "Testing to set the event title"
  end
end
```

Ultimately Event has attributes such as title that will be set from various model associations within the system.  In the example above, Leads is one of them.  Leads will have a drop-down list of possible events so I would want to do something in a before_save whereas the selection in the drop-down ends up setting the event title.  such as:

```
self.events.title = self.selected_event
```

The error I get is the following:

```
undefined method `title=' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fed3229d610>
```

I'm clearly doing this wrong.  I'd appreciate any help at all.  I'm still searching for a solution and will update this myself if I figure it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple events per lead. So, in your situation you'd want to:

```
before_save  :update_events

def update_events
  events.each do |event|
    event.title = "Testing to set the event title"
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I modify that code so it only changes the current event.  Each of the Leads has many events and the above code changes the title for all events, not the new event that is just added.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code to read self.events.last.title = "Testing to set the event title" and that is working for me.  Unless you can think of a better way to do it.